# Trouble while dividing a product

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all sorry for my bad english.

I stumbled upon this term. Is it possible to transform it like that?

---

$$F\times r_1=\frac Q 2\times (r_1-r_2)$$

$$F=\frac Q 2\times \frac {(r_1-r_2)}{r_1}$$

---

I don't understand why $\frac Q2$ doesn't need to be divided by $r_1$.

Hopefully you can help me with this (nooby) question.

Comment: $a\times b=c\times d\implies a =\frac 1b \times c \times d=\frac cb \times d= c \times \frac db$  Does that help?  For the last two we have just used the Associative Property of Multiplication.

Comment: Yes thanks! Seems like i confused myself too much.

Answer (score 0):

It is divided by $r_1$. When you multiply two fractions you get, $$\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$$So in your case, $$F = \frac{Q}{2}\times\frac{r_1-r_2}{r_1}=\frac{Q(r_1-r_2)}{2r_1}$$So, $Q$ is being divided by $r_1$.